# How to refresh only the content in the table not page after click on the pagination button in Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

currently i had develop a page with a table and pagination on it. I only want refresh the  the content in the table after i click on the pagination button but i didn't manage do it even though i follow the example that shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JeMw33wpEw. Anyone can help?

Controller

```
public function view()
{
    $users = DB::table('member')->paginate(10);

    return view('back.member.test', compact( 'users'));
}

public function pindex()
{
    $users = DB::table('member')->paginate(10);
    $data = view('back.member.newTest', compact( 'users'))->render();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Javascript

```
$('.pagination a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var pageid = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[0];
  $.ajax({
    url:"{{URL ::to('newTest')}}",
    data:{page:pageid},
    dataType:'json',
    type:'get',
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('.users').html(data);
    }
  });});
```

Comment: Problem been solved by the owner of the video by moving the javasript file to the header.